# How to use variable inside String.Format

Tags: c#

I want to use `String.Format` inside the loop, but it does not allowing me to define a variable `i` inside the `String.Format`. Here is my code

```
StringBuilder Sb;
for(i=0 ;i<=myObj.length;i++)
{
    Sb=Sb.Append(String.Format("{i,5}",myObj[i].Tostring()));
}
```

Comment: What is that supposed to show? Are you trying to print `i` followed by `myObj[i]`?

Comment: i am trying to generate a fixed width file. i is the index or columns of the array object

Comment: This is going to crash because `<=` should be `!=` or `<`.

Answer (score 4):

To use it in the `Format` method, you use numbers corresponding to the indexes of the params array.

Also, don't reassign `Sb`, just call `Append` or `AppendFormat`:

```
Sb.Append(String.Format("{0,5}", myObj[i].ToString()));
//or
Sb.AppendFormat("{0,5}", myObj[i].ToString());
```

If you're fortunate enough to be on the latest and greatest C# version, you can skip `Format` and do it with the new [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) syntax:

```
Sp.Append($"{myObj[i],5}");
```

Or since all you're doing is padding, then you can also do:

```
Sb.Append(myObj[i].ToString().PadLeft(5));
```

Comment: There is no need to call `ToString()` on `myObj[i]` as it is called by default

Comment: @Luiso Technically calling `ToString()` on a value type  (if the parameters are value types) will prevent the boxing that would occur prior to `ToString`ing the value, and could potentially affect performance slightly (negligible, but still technically not equivalent). I agree though, that personally I would remove `ToString()`.

Comment: The problem using PadLeft/PadRight is that , the last coulmn i need to fill with a blank space of 100 and it is not taking the 100 spaces ,wheres as just taking 8 spaces .